# Row Echelon Form inconsistence

Tags: linear-algebra

So I came across this problem and I was wondering if I could solve it in this manner.

*You are given a vector B and a set of Vectors $X_i$. Decide Whether B is in the span of $X_i$ by attempting to solve the equation $B=x_1X_1+x_2X_2+x_3X_3$.*

So I originally tried to solve via trying to compute the linear combination of $x_iX_i$=B which didn't give me anything useful. So I was thinking since the RREF of $B=x_1X_1+x_2X_2+x_3X_3$ is

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
     0 & 1 & 2 & 2 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

So if the matrix is inconsistent could I therefore show that B is not in the span of $X_i$?

Comment: Yes, assuming that is indeed the correct RREF. In fact, the work has already been done - the last row shows an inconsistency.

Comment: that is so cool!

Comment: Row echelon form is even enough: you just have to decide whether the matrix of the vectors $(X_i)$ and the augmented matrix $(X_i\,B)$ have the same rank.